# Spring - Inject few fields that are not passed through the constructor

Tags: java, spring

I've got three classes. 
`CurrencyUtil` needs `NumberFormatter`. 
`NumberFormatter` is injected into `CurrencyUtilFactory` only because `CurrencyUtil` needs it.

Is there a way to inject `NumberFormatter` directly into `CurrencyUtil`?

Thanks!

**CurrencyUtil**

```
public class CurrencyUtil {
    private final LocalizationHelper localizationHelper; 
    private final NumberFormatter numberFormatter;

    public CurrencyFormatter(final LocalizationHelper localizationHelper, final NumberFormatter numberFormatter) {
        this.localizationHelper = localizationHelper;
        this.numberFormatter = numberFormatter;
    }

    public String prettyPrint(final Currency amount) {

    }
}
```

**CurrencyUtilFactory**

```
public class CurrencyUtilFactory {
    @Autowired
    private NumberFormatter numberFormatter;

    public CurrencyUtil create() {
        ...
        final LocalizationHelper localizationHelper = ....;
        return new CurrencyUtil(localizationHelper, numberFormatter)();
    }

}
```

**NumberFormatter**

```
@Component
public class NumberFormatter {}
```

PS: Apologies for this made up example :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could something like the snippet below work for you? This way you can reuse `CurrencyUtil` with different `amount` values.

```
@Component
public class CurrencyUtil {

    private final NumberFormatter numberFormatter;

    @Autowired
    public CurrencyFormatter(NumberFormatter numberFormatter) {
        this.numberFormatter = numberFormatter;
    }

    public String prettyPrint(Currency amount) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Update** (based on the adjusted question)

Spring can autowire only beans that it knows. If your beans (or some of them) are not managed with Spring, you have to autowire them on your own (e.g. via a constructor as you did). The solution could be:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    private NumberFormatter numberFormatter;

    @Autowired
    private LocalizationHelper localizationHelper;

    @Bean
    public CurrencyUtil curencyUtil() {
        return new CurrencyUtil(localizationHelper, numberFormatter);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Or

```
@Component
public class CurrencyUtil {

    private LocalizationHelper helper;

    private NumberFormatter numberFormatter;

    @Autowired
    public CurrencyFormatter(LocalizationHelper helper, NumberFormatter numberFormatter) {
        this.helper = helper;
        this.numberFormatter = numberFormatter;
    }

    public String prettyPrint(Currency amount) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did a bad job with the example. I fixed it now. Essentially, NumberFactory is autowired into CurrencyUtilFactory only because CurrencyUtil needs it. Is there a way to Autowire it into CurrencyUtil directly?

Comment: How would you like to inject anything into `CurrencyUtil` if it is not a Spring managed bean? Maybe JavaConfig could help. Look at the updated answer.